# Render multiple tables flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have my Flask file that calls some endpoints to fetch some data. If form 1 is submitted it performs the filter with the required data to the db and applies the same with form 2, both are rendered in the same html page.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        div_id = request.form.get('div_id')

        # Verificar qué formulario se envió
        if 'tabla_sitio_fecha_inicio' in request.form and 'tabla_sitio_fecha_fin' in request.form:
            # Si se envió el formulario dos
            start_date = request.form['tabla_sitio_fecha_inicio']
            end_date = request.form['tabla_sitio_fecha_fin']
            filtro = request.form['tabla_sitio_filtro']
            valor = request.form['tabla_sitio_valor']
            datos1 = obtener_datos_por_fechas(start_date, end_date, filtro, valor)

            return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data1=datos1, scroll_to_div=div_id)
        
        elif 'tabla_sitio_gral_filtro' in request.form and 'tabla_sitio_gral_valor' in request.form:
            # Si se envió el formulario uno
            ts_gral_filtro = request.form['tabla_sitio_gral_filtro']
            ts_gral_valor = request.form['tabla_sitio_gral_valor']
            datos2 = obtener_datos_por_filtro(ts_gral_filtro, ts_gral_valor)

            return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data2=datos2, scroll_to_div=div_id)
        else:
            return "Error: formulario inválido"
    else:     
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # Si no es una solicitud POST, obtener datos iniciales
            datos_iniciales = obtener_datos_iniciales()

            if datos_iniciales is not None:
                return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data=datos_iniciales, scroll_to_div=None)
            else:
                return "Error al obtener datos iniciales"
```

Up to here it works well. My problem is when sending some form from the html, it updates me the corresponding table but it eliminates the data of the other table, remaining empty.

Is there any way that when sending the form only updates me the corresponding table and the data of the other table remain as they were before reloading the page?

This is one of my tables. The other one has a similar operation but it obtains the data of the other variable.

```
<tbody>
                    {% if fetched_data2 is defined %}
                        {% for data in fetched_data2 %}
                            <!-- Mostrar datos iniciales -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[0] }}" name="cliente_0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[1] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[2] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[3] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[22] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% for data in fetched_data %}
                            <!-- Mostrar datos filtrados -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[0] }}" name="cliente_0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[1] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[2] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[3] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[22] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
```